# Basic LED chaser animation loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, arduino

I'm attempting to emulate an infinite looping chaser on an LED strip with Javascript.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- Only use loops or recursive functions. No fancy JS.
- Support any length of LED strip (`var ledLength`)
- Support of multiple chasers
- Support any number of LEDs (`var ledDepth`) with any number
  of spaces separating the chasers (`var blankDepth`)
- Loop infinitely
- No magic numbers

I have this working for 1 chaser:

```
$(function(){

  var ledLength = 20;

  for(var i = 0; i < ledLength; i++) {
    $('#led').append($('<div>').addClass('node'));
  }

  $('#led').css('width', ($('.node').length + 1) * $('.node').last().outerWidth(true));

  var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue'];
  // add a "clearing" color
  colors.push('black');

  var ledDepth = 3;
  var blankDepth = 2;
  var chaserSize = ledDepth + blankDepth;

  var iteration = 0;

  var loop = setInterval(animate, 250);

  function animate() {

    if(iteration == ledLength + ledDepth) iteration = 0;

    var offset = iteration < chaserSize ? iteration : chaserSize;

    for(var i = 0; i <= offset; i ++) {
      var colorOffset = i < ledDepth ? i : ledDepth;
      $('.node').eq(iteration-i).css('background', colors[colorOffset]);
    }
    iteration++;
  }
});
```

Or you can view it on the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gelihuwo/1/).

How would I go about tracking multiple chasers on a strip? Meaning after the initial `chaserSize` has been created and is moving to the right, another would be created and move long with it and loop infinitely.

Any help in to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to take a different approach to this using an array.push method.

Basically, I continue to add points, loop through them all to increase their location, and remove them if their location is greater than the length of the strip.

This works for all LED lengths, chaser sizes (colors + blanks between each chaser).

Code:

```
$(function(){


  // create the strip
  var ledLength = 30;
  for(var i = 0; i < ledLength; i++) {
    $('#led').append($('<div>').addClass('node'));
  }
  $('#led').css('width', ($('.node').length + 1) * $('.node').last().outerWidth(true));

  var points = [];

  var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'pink', 'orange', 'purple'];

  var ledDepth = colors.length || 6;
  var blankDepth = 2;
  var chaserSize = ledDepth + blankDepth;

  // push blank nodes on the back of colors array
  for(var i = 0; i < blankDepth; i++) {
    colors.push('blank');
  }

  var iteration = 0;

  // loop!
  var loop = setInterval(animate, 100);

  function animate() {

    if(points.length) {
      for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        // increase each pin by 1
        points[i].pin++;
        // remove point if pin is greater than led length
        if(points[i].pin > ledLength) {
          points.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }

    if(iteration < chaserSize) {
      points.push({pin: 0, color: colors[iteration]});
    }

    // draw points
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      if(points[i].color == 'blank') { // this if for 'resetting'
        $('.node').eq(points[i].pin).css('background', 'black');
      } else { // this is for changing color
        $('.node').eq(points[i].pin).css('background', points[i].color);
      }
    }

    // iterate before reset
    iteration++;

    // reset sub-iterator (creator)
    if(iteration >= chaserSize) {
      iteration = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

Or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gopusuqi/1/)